# Who Counted More?

Tags: logical-deduction

Two persons, one standing at the door of his house and the other walking up and down the pavement, were counting passers-by for a whole hour. Who counted more?

> Source: - [From here.](https://books.google.co.in/books/about/Mathematics_Can_Be_Fun.html?id=P5wAOwAACAAJ&source=kp_book_description&redir_esc=y)

Comment: Is the pavement perpendicular to the driveway of the house?

Comment: No, It is parallel.

Comment: So he is going towards and then away from the house?

Comment: He is just walking along the road.

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think both count same number of passers, both are viewing same road even if second person walk along the pavement passers don't change

Comment: I think there are a lot of hidden assumptions in the question and this answer. If someone walks part way up the street, then turns around and leaves, will the person in the doorway count them even if they don't pass the house? Does the person who is counting and walking up and down start and finish at the other persons house? Is he considered a passer-by to the other person? etc.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Also: does the puzzle suggest the answer should actually refer to _passers_ or to _passes_? And: is the person standing still a _passer_...?